# Finding the avg. revenue for each sales rep

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to find the average monthly revenue for each sales owner--however my current query is taking the monthly total and just dividing it by the number of entries. Ultimately, I'd like to get the average by finding the total revenue for each month and then dividing it by the number of months and then eventually just finding the avg. of the past 6 months. Code as well as sample output below:

```
select activitydate, console_org_name, partneragency, partneradvertiser, org_sales_owner
    ,round(sum(gross_revenue_allocation)::numeric,2) as gross_revenue   
    ,round(avg(sum(gross_revenue_allocation)) over (partition by org_sales_owner order by activitydate RANGE INTERVAL '5' MONTH PRECEDING)::numeric,2) as salesowner6monthavg   
from data_provider_payout dpp   
where activitydate >= '01/01/2019'
group by activitydate, console_org_name, partneragency, partneradvertiser, org_sales_owner
```

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: Do you want to include non-sales, those with value = 0?

Comment: You will need to do a query that calculates the monthly averages for each `org_sales_owner`, then use that as a subquery of the one that then takes these results and averages them over the number of months.

Comment: @WillWalsh can you assist in creating that subquery? Still starting out in SQL.

Comment: That's not a query I can do in my head and I don't have the time to set up a schema and test data at the moment I'm afraid. If the query above already averages the data over the number of entries for 6 months, you should be able to adjust it to be just 1 month and that's the subquery. Then write the existing query around that subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to aggregate by the month and the owner.  That would be something like this:

```
select date_trunc('month', activitydate), org_sales_owner,
       round(sum(gross_revenue_allocation)::numeric, 2) as gross_revenue, 
       round(avg(sum(gross_revenue_allocation)) over (
                      partition by org_sales_owner
                      order by min(activitydate) 
                      range between interval '5 month' preceding and current_row
                     )
                )::numeric, 2) as salesowner6monthavg   
from data_provider_payout dpp   
where activitydate >= '2019-01-01'
group by date_trunc('month', activitydate), org_sales_owner
```

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff -- thanks but it looks like it's still not calculating the average correctly. Here's a sample output: https://imgur.com/yZnlvFa. Ultimately the goal is to take the average of the total month to month.